# Updating html template not show in Magento 2 Checkout page

Tags: magento2, checkout, template

I use Magento 2.0 for the first time and I am trying to make some changes on Checkout page. For example, I want to change template 
`module-checkout/view/frontend/web/template/estimation.html`, 
so I copied this template to my folder theme to 
`'Magento_Checkout/web/template/estimation.html'` 
and I made some changes in it, but nothing changes. Also, for a test, I changed original template but still, no changes.

I use grunt, I deployed the code, cleared all cache. On every other pages, changes do apply, but not on checkout. Do you have any guess, what am I doing wrong?

Also a question - is there any better explanation on how does checkout page on Magento2 work than the one from Magento page?

Comment: you have to delete cache and regenerate static content `php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy` & `php bin/magento cache:clean`

Comment: I did that - no changes.

Comment: Please try opening the page in incognito/private window as the static content are also cached by browser.

Comment: For example in Chrome private window - changes now show. In Mozilla not, I cleared all cookies also, but still nothing.

Comment: try deleting browser cache - https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/how-clear-firefox-cache

Comment: You're great! :) It shows the changes. Thank you.

Comment: Glad! It was helpful.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In your case, the **Browser Cache** caused your issue, we should **disable** it when developing and testing.

**Chrome Browser**

[image]

**Firefox**

[image]

> is there any better explanation on how does checkout page on Magento 2
>   work than the one from Magento page?

I'm not sure my explanation is good enough to understand.

We need to take a look: `vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/layout/checkout_index_index.xml`. We will see a lot of config nodes. Magento layout for one page checkout comes from here.

Navigate to `vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/templates/onepage.phtml`:

```
 <script type="text/x-magento-init">
        {
            "#checkout": {
                "Magento_Ui/js/core/app": <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getJsLayout();?>
            }
        }
    </script>
    <script>
        window.checkoutConfig = <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo \Zend_Json::encode($block->getCheckoutConfig()); ?>;
        // Create aliases for customer.js model from customer module
        window.isCustomerLoggedIn = window.checkoutConfig.isCustomerLoggedIn;
        window.customerData = window.checkoutConfig.customerData;
    </script>
```

The most logic is here. `$block->getJsLayout()` gets the config from the xml layout. The js `Magento_Ui/js/core/app` is in charge of the rendering UI. There are some global javascript variables. These variables are used for other js components.

For the js and html templates file, Magento will load them from `pub/static`. They are copied to `pub/static` after running static content deploy.

Comment: plz check once http://syhdsshoponline.com.au/  what is the issue, sorry for asking here

Answer (score 6):

Follow below steps for view your changes

Delete var folder

Delete pub/static/

Run bellow commands for generate static content and clean cache.

> `php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy`
>
> `php bin/magento cache:clean`

**deleting browser cache**

Now check your changes.

Comment: "Delete `pub/static/`" is not advisable. The `pub/static/.htaccess` is an important file necessary for cache and static files generation. Deleting this file will make you spiral down the "static files issue" hole and waste your evening.

Answer (score 0):

```
bin/magento setup:upgrade && bin/magento cache:clean
```

command worked for me.