# Magento 2 - Change the order of the Shipping fields on the Checkout page

Tags: magento2, checkout, shipping, magento-2.0, shipping-address

I would like to change the order of the Shipping fields on the Checkout page so that they display in the following order:

- Your Email
- Street
- City
- State
- Zip Code
- First Name
- Last Name
- Phone Number

From the research I have done, the way to approach this seems to edit the `checkout_index_index.xml` file. However, when I flush the static cache and run `php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy` I do not see changes to my Shipping Address fields.

The following are the contents of my `checkout_index_index.xml`

```
    <referenceBlock name="checkout.root">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="jsLayout" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="components" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="checkout" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="steps" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                    <item name="shipping-step" xsi:type="array">
                                        <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                            <item name="shippingAddress" xsi:type="array">
                                                <item name="component" xsi:type="string">MilkJarCookies_OrderDeliveryDate/js/view/shipping</item>
                                                <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                    <item name="shipping-address-fieldset" xsi:type="array">
                                                        <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                            <item name="region_id" xsi:type="array">
                                                                <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="string">87</item>
                                                            </item>
                                                            <item name="postcode" xsi:type="array">
                                                                <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="string">80</item>
                                                            </item>
                                                            <item name="company" xsi:type="array">
                                                                <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="string">100</item>
                                                            </item>
                                                            <item name="vat_id" xsi:type="array">
                                                                <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="string">1</item>
                                                            </item>
                                                            <item name="country_id" xsi:type="array">
                                                                <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="string">85</item>
                                                            </item>
                                                            <item name="telephone" xsi:type="array">
                                                                <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="string">90</item>
                                                            </item>
                                                        </item>
                                                    </item>
                                                </item>
                                            </item>
                                        </item>
                                    </item>
                                </item>
                            </item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </referenceBlock>
</body>
```

Comment: Try to disable Browser cache: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/135918/updating-template-in-magento-2-checkout-page/

Comment: Can you tell me which checkout_index_index.xml is this? There are so many of this in different modules.  Can you tell me the path?

Comment: @OliverSchmid its the one in the Checkout module... vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/layout

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/135920/54588

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From past experience making changes to knockout templates, you may need to manually remove the contents of the `pub/static` folder (preserve the `.htaccess` file):

> rm -rf pub/static/*

Answer (score 1):

**After Change layout you need to remove configuration cache **

Run the below command to remove configuration cache

```
php bin/magento cache:clean config
php bin/magento cache:flush config
```

After that reload it will work.