# How to change the order of the billing address fields on checkout page in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, checkout, onepage-checkout, knockoutjs

I want to change the ordering of Address fields for both shipping address and billing address on checkout page

I have changed the order of shipping Address and is working fine (***[thanks to this answer](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/139557)***)

The following is the content of My theme's `checkout_index_index.xml` layout file

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="checkout" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
          <referenceBlock name="checkout.root">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="jsLayout" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="components" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="checkout" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="steps" xsi:type="array">
                                    <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                        <item name="shipping-step" xsi:type="array">
                                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                <item name="shippingAddress" xsi:type="array">
                                                    <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                        <item name="shipping-address-fieldset" xsi:type="array">
                                                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                                <item name="country_id" xsi:type="array">
                                                                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="string">85</item>
                                                                </item>
                                                                <item name="region_id" xsi:type="array">
                                                                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="string">87</item>
                                                                </item>
                                                                <item name="city" xsi:type="array">
                                                                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="string">90</item>
                                                                </item>
                                                                <item name="postcode" xsi:type="array">
                                                                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="string">91</item>
                                                                </item>
                                                                <item name="telephone" xsi:type="array">
                                                                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="string">94</item>
                                                                </item>
                                                            </item>
                                                        </item>
                                                    </item>
                                                </item>
                                            </item>
                                        </item>
                                    </item>
                                </item>
                            </item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </argument>
            </arguments>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

But when I tried to update order of Billing address it did not changed. I have also checked the original `checkout_index_index.xml` layout file in `Magento_Checkout` module there is not fields in `billing-step`.

Do anyone know how to do this ?

Comment: Did you found any solution?

Comment: No, I did not find solution to it I end up using the default order. but if you do, be kind to share it so it may help others.

Answer (score 11):

Here is an example (using Plugin) for changing field order, disabling field or adding missing field to address.

File:  **etc/di.xml**

```
<type name="Magento\Checkout\Block\Checkout\LayoutProcessor">
    <plugin disabled="false" name="Vendor_Module_Plugin_Block_Checkout_LayoutProcessor" sortOrder="99"
                type="Vendor\Module\Plugin\Block\Checkout\LayoutProcessor"/>
</type>
```

File: **Plugin/Block/Checkout/LayoutProcessor.php**

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Plugin\Block\Checkout;

use Magento\Checkout\Block\Checkout\LayoutProcessor as MageLayoutProcessor;

class LayoutProcessor
{
    public function afterProcess(MageLayoutProcessor $subject, $jsLayout)
    {

        /* config: checkout/options/display_billing_address_on = payment_method */
        if (isset($jsLayout['components']['checkout']['children']['steps']['children']['billing-step']['children']
            ['payment']['children']['payments-list']['children']
        )) {

            foreach ($jsLayout['components']['checkout']['children']['steps']['children']['billing-step']['children']
                     ['payment']['children']['payments-list']['children'] as $key => $payment) {

                /* company */
                if (isset($payment['children']['form-fields']['children']['company'])) {

                    $jsLayout['components']['checkout']['children']['steps']['children']['billing-step']['children']
                    ['payment']['children']['payments-list']['children'][$key]['children']['form-fields']['children']
                    ['company']['sortOrder'] = 0;
                }

                /* region & region_id */
                if (isset($payment['children']['form-fields']['children']['region'])) {

                    $jsLayout['components']['checkout']['children']['steps']['children']['billing-step']['children']
                    ['payment']['children']['payments-list']['children'][$key]['children']['form-fields']['children']
                    ['region']['visible'] = false;

                    $jsLayout['components']['checkout']['children']['steps']['children']['billing-step']['children']
                    ['payment']['children']['payments-list']['children'][$key]['children']['form-fields']['children']
                    ['region']['config']['componentDisabled'] = true;
                }
                if (isset($payment['children']['form-fields']['children']['region_id'])) {

                    $jsLayout['components']['checkout']['children']['steps']['children']['billing-step']['children']
                    ['payment']['children']['payments-list']['children'][$key]['children']['form-fields']['children']
                    ['region_id']['visible'] = false;

                    $jsLayout['components']['checkout']['children']['steps']['children']['billing-step']['children']
                    ['payment']['children']['payments-list']['children'][$key]['children']['form-fields']['children']
                    ['region_id']['config']['componentDisabled'] = true;
                }

                $method = substr($key, 0, -5);

                /* vat_id */
                $jsLayout['components']['checkout']['children']['steps']['children']['billing-step']['children']
                ['payment']['children']['payments-list']['children'][$key]['children']['form-fields']['children']
                ['vat_id'] = [
                    'component' => 'Magento_Ui/js/form/element/abstract',
                    'config' => [
                        'customScope' => 'billingAddress' . $method,
                        'customEntry' => null,
                        'template' => 'ui/form/field',
                        'elementTmpl' => 'ui/form/element/input',
                        'tooltip' => null,
                    ],
                    'dataScope' => 'billingAddress' . $method . '.vat_id',
                    'dataScopePrefix' => 'billingAddress' . $method,
                    'label' => __('VAT number'),
                    'provider' => 'checkoutProvider',
                    'sortOrder' => 1,
                    'validation' => [],
                    'options' => [],
                    'filterBy' => null,
                    'customEntry' => null,
                    'visible' => true,
                ];
            }
        }

        /* config: checkout/options/display_billing_address_on = payment_page */
        if (isset($jsLayout['components']['checkout']['children']['steps']['children']['billing-step']['children']
            ['payment']['children']['afterMethods']['children']['billing-address-form']
        )) {

            /* company */
            if (isset($jsLayout['components']['checkout']['children']['steps']['children']['billing-step']['children']
                ['payment']['children']['afterMethods']['children']['billing-address-form']['children']['form-fields']
                ['children']['company']
            )) {
                $jsLayout['components']['checkout']['children']['steps']['children']['billing-step']['children']
                ['payment']['children']['afterMethods']['children']['billing-address-form']['children']['form-fields']
                ['children']['company']['sortOrder'] = 0;
            }

            /* region & region_id */
            if (isset($jsLayout['components']['checkout']['children']['steps']['children']['billing-step']['children']
                ['payment']['children']['afterMethods']['children']['billing-address-form']['children']['form-fields']
                ['children']['region'])) {

                $jsLayout['components']['checkout']['children']['steps']['children']['billing-step']['children']
                ['payment']['children']['afterMethods']['children']['billing-address-form']['children']['form-fields']
                ['children']['region']['visible'] = false;

                $jsLayout['components']['checkout']['children']['steps']['children']['billing-step']['children']
                ['payment']['children']['afterMethods']['children']['billing-address-form']['children']['form-fields']
                ['children']['region']['config']['componentDisabled'] = true;
            }
            if (isset($jsLayout['components']['checkout']['children']['steps']['children']['billing-step']['children']
                ['payment']['children']['afterMethods']['children']['billing-address-form']['children']['form-fields']
                ['children']['region_id'])) {

                $jsLayout['components']['checkout']['children']['steps']['children']['billing-step']['children']
                ['payment']['children']['afterMethods']['children']['billing-address-form']['children']['form-fields']
                ['children']['region_id']['visible'] = false;

                $jsLayout['components']['checkout']['children']['steps']['children']['billing-step']['children']
                ['payment']['children']['afterMethods']['children']['billing-address-form']['children']['form-fields']
                ['children']['region_id']['config']['componentDisabled'] = true;
            }

            $method = 'shared';

            /* vat_id */
            $jsLayout['components']['checkout']['children']['steps']['children']['billing-step']['children']
            ['payment']['children']['afterMethods']['children']['billing-address-form']['children']['form-fields']
            ['children']['vat_id'] = [
                'component' => 'Magento_Ui/js/form/element/abstract',
                'config' => [
                    'customScope' => 'billingAddress' . $method,
                    'customEntry' => null,
                    'template' => 'ui/form/field',
                    'elementTmpl' => 'ui/form/element/input',
                    'tooltip' => null,
                ],
                'dataScope' => 'billingAddress' . $method . '.vat_id',
                'dataScopePrefix' => 'billingAddress' . $method,
                'label' => __('VAT number'),
                'provider' => 'checkoutProvider',
                'sortOrder' => 1,
                'validation' => [],
                'options' => [],
                'filterBy' => null,
                'customEntry' => null,
                'visible' => true,
            ];
        }

        return $jsLayout;
    }
}
```

Comment: how do you save this value to the DB?

Answer (score 3):

I know its been a while since the question was asked but I had the same issue and found the solution for doing a field re-order for the billing address forms. In my case I need to move the telephone field above the country field.

Please see below for XML layout update:

```
<!-- Update field order -->
    <referenceBlock name="checkout.root">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="jsLayout" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="components" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="checkout" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="steps" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                    <item name="billing-step" xsi:type="array">
                                        <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                            <item name="payment" xsi:type="array">
                                                <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                    <item name="payments-list" xsi:type="array">
                                                        <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                            <item name="sagepaysuiteserver-form" xsi:type="array">
                                                                <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                                    <item name="form-fields" xsi:type="array">
                                                                        <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                                            <item name="telephone" xsi:type="array">
                                                                                <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="string">114</item>
                                                                            </item>
                                                                        </item>
                                                                    </item>
                                                                </item>
                                                            </item>
                                                            <item name="checkmo-form" xsi:type="array">
                                                                <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                                    <item name="form-fields" xsi:type="array">
                                                                        <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                                            <item name="telephone" xsi:type="array">
                                                                                <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="string">114</item>
                                                                            </item>
                                                                        </item>
                                                                    </item>
                                                                </item>
                                                            </item>
                                                        </item>
                                                    </item>
                                                </item>
                                            </item>
                                        </item>
                                    </item>
                                </item>
                            </item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </referenceBlock>
```

Comment: If you need to debug it, take a look into `\Magento\CustomerCustomAttributes\Block\Checkout\renderer::process(()`

Comment: This solution is slightly less maintainable than the most upvoted answer (i.e. `LayoutProcessor` plugin) because you need to edit the xml whenever the list of payment methods changes.

Answer (score 2):

**Change sort order of billing address field**

- Create a custom module
- create file etc/di.xml

  ```
  <!-- Billing address form changes plugin -->
  <type name="Magento\Checkout\Block\Checkout\LayoutProcessor">
      <plugin disabled="false" name="Namespace_Module_Plugin_Block_Checkout_LayoutProcessor" sortOrder="100"
          type="Namespace\Module\Plugin\Block\Checkout\LayoutProcessor"/>
  </type>
  ```
- Create layout processor block class

  ```
          <?php
          namespace Namespace\Module\Plugin\Block\Checkout;

          use Namespace\Module\Block\Checkout\LayoutProcessor as MagentoLayoutProcessor;


          class LayoutProcessor
          {

              public function afterProcess(MagentoLayoutProcessor $subject, $jsLayout)
              {
              if (isset($jsLayout['components']['checkout']['children']['steps']['children']['billing-step']['children']
                  ['payment']['children']['payments-list']['children']
              )) {

                  foreach ($jsLayout['components']['checkout']['children']['steps']['children']['billing-step']['children']
                       ['payment']['children']['payments-list']['children'] as $key => $payment) {

                  /* company */
                  if (isset($payment['children']['form-fields']['children']['company'])) {
                      $jsLayout['components']['checkout']['children']['steps']['children']['billing-step']['children']
                      ['payment']['children']['payments-list']['children'][$key]['children']['form-fields']['children']
                      ['company']['sortOrder'] = 10;
                  }


                  }

                  }

              }
              return $jsLayout;
              }
          }
  ```

Comment: how do you save this value to the DB?