# How to customize checkout page in magento 2?

Tags: magento2, checkout, magento2.2.6, order-email

Is it possible to sort the order of email field at the top of the page after lastname field in shipping form?
Is there any way to bring remove login part in checkout page and bring email field after last name field?

Answer (score 0):

You can disable the Login From Checkout. 
Override email.phtml file in your theme.

> app/design/frontend/Vendor_name/Module/Magento_Checkout/web/template/form/element/email.html

Comment Or Remove Following Span from that.

```
<!-- <span class="note" data-bind="fadeVisible: isPasswordVisible() == false"> -->
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. This will remove login part but how to sort this  email field after last name field?

Comment: You can not move that email field after LastName, because there are 2 different forms, One for Email & Password & another for Shipping Address. If you want to add Email field after LastName, Then Add New Field via Layout Processor.

Comment: Have you got it?

Comment: Yes. Got it. But how to remove validation for email field?

Comment: Email field is required to place order. we can not set it to be empty.

Answer (score 0):

For the short order form field you should use following way in **XML** file

> app/code/Vendor/Checkout/view/frontend/layout/checkout_index_index.xml

```
<item name="lastname" xsi:type="array">
    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="string">20</item>
</item>
```

For more reference [Click here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/139557/magento-2-change-the-order-of-the-shipping-fields-on-the-checkout-page)

I hope it helps!